# Should "in" be used with "aiding and abetting"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Aiding and abetting, also sometimes aiding or abetting, is often found in legal definitions of accessorial liability for crimes, for example "aiding or abetting a felony."

Is it proper to use "in" after "aiding (and/or) abetting"?  Is either of the following examples more proper, or is either improper?

**Example A1:**  "The law creates criminal penalties for aiding or abetting in the preparation or commission of a murder."

**Example A2:**  "The law creates criminal penalties for aiding or abetting the preparation or commission of a murder."

Does it make any difference if you drop "preparation or commission of"?  Examples:

**Example B1:**  "The law creates criminal penalties for aiding or abetting in a murder."

**Example B2:**  "The law creates criminal penalties for aiding or abetting a murder."

One thought is that it may be proper to use "in" in these circumstances, when referring to the  act; "in" would be improper when referring to the actor.

**Example C1:**  "The law creates criminal penalties for aiding or abetting a murderer."

The dictionary example usages I've found omit "in."  See, e.g., [here](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/abet).  But while searching for an answer, I see a lot of use of "in."  That said, much of that use is in the context of legislation, and I never assume the intelligence of a politician, and *especially* not a group of politicians!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need the *in* in any of these sentences.

This becomes clear when you read this definition of aid and abet from a [law dictionary](http://law.yourdictionary.com/aid-and-abet):

*aid and abet (verb) —
To order, encourage, facilitate, or to actively, knowingly, intentionally, or purposefully assist, or otherwise promote or attempt to promote the commission of a crime or a tort. Affirmative conduct is regarded; aiding and abetting cannot be established by omission or negative acquiescence.*

So when you substitute *ordering*, *encouraging*, or *facilitating* into your examples, you get:

"The law creates criminal penalties for encouraging the preparation or commission of a murder."

"The law creates criminal penalties for encouraging a murderer."

"The law creates criminal penalties for facilitating the preparation or commission of a murder."

"The law creates criminal penalties for ordering a murder."

Interestingly, I saw one definition of *aid and abet* [here](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Aid+and+Abet) that said it is "a lawyer redundancy since abet means aid, which lends credence to the old rumor that lawyers used to be paid by the word."

Answer (score 0):

The term *aiding and abetting* has effectively become a compound unit in itself - as JLG indicates, the three-word conjunction really has a single meaning. The sequence ["aiding **and** abetting a"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22100s%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22aiding%20and%20abetting%20a%22&oq=%22aiding%20and%20abetting%20a%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=10760l13536l13l13847l5l0l5l0l0l0l0l0ll5l0&gs_l=serp.3...10760l13536l13l13847l5l0l5l0l0l0l0l0ll5l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859) gets 226K hits in Google Books, as opposed to only 30K for ["aiding **or** abetting a"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22100s%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22aiding%20or%20abetting%20a%22&oq=%22aiding%20or%20abetting%20a%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=73181l74212l14l74587l5l0l5l0l0l0l0l0ll5l0&gs_l=serp.3...73181l74212l14l74587l5l0l5l0l0l0l0l0ll5l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859). So don't use *"or"*.

And since ["aiding and abetting **in** a"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22100s%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22aiding%20and%20abetting%20in%20a%22&oq=%22aiding%20and%20abetting%20in%20a%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=61659l65331l15l65978l8l3l5l0l0l0l46l133l3l8l0&gs_l=serp.3...61659l65331l15l65978l8l3l5l0l0l0l46l133l3l8l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859) gets only 11K hits, I'd advise against using *"in"* as well.